# branch name with same prefix will have same access control in gitolite

Tags: git, branch, prefix, access-control, gitolite

I wrote `gitolite.conf` file:

```
repo Lib
   RW+     = git
   RW  dev = fabby
   RW  develop = fabby
   RW  dev_tele = fabby
```

1. `fabby` can not only make changes on `dev`, `develop` and `dev_tele`,
2. but can also on branches with `dev` prefix like `dev1`, `dev_1`, `devdd` or `dev_drv`...
3. `fabby` can not make changes on branches with `dev` postfix like `mdev`

so how can I edit `gitolite.conf` file, and make `fabby` only have write access control on branch `dev`, `develop` and `dev_tele`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), this is how "refexes" are treated:

> Note 2: refex matching:
>
> (refex = optional regex to match the ref being pushed)
>
> - an empty refex is treated as 'refs/.*'
> - a refex that does not start with 'refs/' is prefixed with 'refs/heads/'
> - finally, a '^' is prefixed
> - the ref being pushed is matched against this resulting refex

Since "refexes" are regular expressions, and the system automatically prefixes them with `^refs/heads/`, this explains your experience. (In regular expressions, the `^` character is an anchor to match the beginning of a line.)

Adding a `$` to the end of your branches should anchor the end as well, giving you the results you want:

```
repo Lib
   RW+     = git
   RW  dev$ = fabby
   RW  develop$ = fabby
   RW  dev_tele$ = fabby
```

This will cause Gitolite to see, e.g., `^refs/heads/dev$`, which should match your `dev` branch name exactly.